# What do Oracle DB name and SID mean?

Tags: oracle10g

What is the relation between two Oracle database terms `name` and `SID`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Oracle difference between SID, DB Name, DB Domain, Global Database Name, Service Name, Service Alias and Instance Name](https://serverfault.com/questions/49509/oracle-difference-between-sid-db-name-db-domain-global-database-name-service)

Comment: One more question: where can I get DB Name, Db Domain? are they in some metadata?

Answer (score -1):

good answers in [oracle forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=280913)